# How to get all PageTemplate that contains a specific component?

Tags: c#, sitecore, lucene.net, sitecore8, sitecore-lucene

I have a pagetemplate called `ArticlePageTemplate`. This `ArticlePageTemplate` contains a component called `Articles`. The `Article` component has data field called `Header`, `SubHeader`, `Date`, and `Content`.

[image]

### Presentation details of `ArticlesPageTemplate`

[image: Presentation details of page]

Using Lucene in sitecore 8. How do I get all ArticlePageTemplate that contains an Article component with the value of "News" in subheader of Article component.

Sitecore structure:

[image: Sitecore tree]

### Here is my code

```
public class LuceneSearchService : ILuceneSearchService, IDisposable
{
    bool disposed = false;
    // Instantiate a SafeHandle instance.
    SafeHandle handle = new SafeFileHandle(IntPtr.Zero, true);

    private IProviderSearchContext _SearchContext;
    private ISearchIndex _Index;

    private string _IndexName = "sitecore_web_index";

    public string IndexName
    {
        get { return _IndexName; }
        set { _IndexName = value; }
    }


    public LuceneSearchService()
    {
        _Index = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex(this.IndexName);
        _SearchContext = _Index.CreateSearchContext();
    }

    public IQueryable<SearchResultItem> PerformSearch(string searchPath)
    {

        var searchQuery = _SearchContext.GetQueryable<SearchResultItem>()
        .Where(i => i.Path.StartsWith(searchPath));

        return searchQuery;

    }

    public IQueryable<SearchResultItem> PerformSearch(string searchPath, string templateName)
    {
        var searchQuery = PerformSearch(searchPath).Where(x => x.TemplateName == templateName);

        return searchQuery;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);            
    }

    // Protected implementation of Dispose pattern. 
    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposed)
            return;

        if (disposing)
        {
            handle.Dispose();
            _SearchContext.Dispose();
            _Index.Dispose();
        }

        // Free any unmanaged objects here. 
        //
        disposed = true;
    }
}
```

### Code implementation

```
public void SearchArticles()
    {
        var articles = SearchService.PerformSearch("/sitecore/content", "ArticlePageTemplate").ToList();
        foreach (var article in articles){
            var articleName = article;
        }


    }
```

I can get all the `ArticlesPageTemplate` using the code above but I can't filter it to get only those `ArticlePageTemplate` that contains an `Article` component in which `Article` component's subheader is "news".

I do not know how to get the articles component of `ArticlePageTemplate` so I could add them to my search query in lucene.

Any advice is appreciated.

**Note:**

The datasource of `ArticlesComponent` may change so it is not always a child of `ArticlesPageTemplate`.

**UPDATE (09/11/2015)**

I tried what Richard suggested but it does not work.

```
var articles = SearchService
        .PerformSearch<ArticleResultItem>("/sitecore/content", "ArticlePageTemplate")
        .Where(item => item.SubHeader == "News").ToList();
```

Using the above query does not yield any result but using the below query returns a result but it retrieves ArticleComponent instead of ArticlePageTemplate.

```
var articles = SearchService
        .PerformSearch<ArticleResultItem>("/sitecore/content"
        .Where(item => item.SubHeader == "News").ToList();
```

**SOLUTION:**

Computed fields works. See VisualizationField.cs from the link below:

https://gist.github.com/techphoria414/7604814

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see two approaches that you can go with here:

- **Build a 'computed field' for the Article component subheader field.** You would set this up so that the index is configured to look for this component on an item with the ArticlePageTemplate template and compute the subheader value into the index. This essentially makes the index think that the subheader field is actually a field on ArticlePageTemplate item. Then you can do a regular search on the index.
- **Find the reference pages for a component.** In this scenario, you search the index for the components (not ArticlePageTemplate), and if you can depend on your folder structure and you do not have re-use across pages, you can then just grab the parent page of any search result. (item.Parent.Parent, in your example structure)

**UPDATE:** Some links for computed fields:

- http://www.sitecore.net/learn/blogs/technical-blogs/john-west-sitecore-blog/posts/2013/03/sitecore-7-computed-index-fields.aspx
- https://gist.github.com/techphoria414/7604814

Comment: Hi Jay, I also tried item.Parent.Parent but item.Parent does not have a property called Parent.

Comment: HI @Pinoy2015, for the first approach, computed fields are pieces of code that you write and configure in the index so an item can get data it would not normally get. I'll find a link and add to my original answer.

I'm not sure about your item.Parent issue, though. The Parent property should return an Item, which should mean it should also have a Parent property.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to create a custom class that allows you to filter on your field, you can base it off the `SearchResultItem` class.

So something like:

```
public class ArticleResultItem : SearchResultItem
{
    [IndexField("SubHeader")]
    public string SubHeader { get;set; }
}
```

Then if you change your `PerformSearch` method to take a generic based of `SearchResultItem`, you can filter using that field in your calling method.

```
public IQueryable<T> PerformSearch<T>(string searchPath)
    where T: SearchResultItem
{

    var searchQuery = _SearchContext.GetQueryable<T>()
    .Where(i => i.Path.StartsWith(searchPath));

    return searchQuery;

}

public IQueryable<T> PerformSearch<T>(string searchPath, string templateName)
    where T: SearchResultItem
{
    var searchQuery = PerformSearch<T>(searchPath).Where(x => x.TemplateName == templateName);

    return searchQuery;
}
```

And then you would call it like this:

```
public void SearchArticles()
{
    var articles = SearchService
        .PerformSearch<ArticleResultItem>("/sitecore/content", "ArticlePageTemplate")
        .Where(item => item.SubHeader == "News").ToList();
    foreach (var article in articles){
        var articleName = article;
        // Do something with the list here....
    }
}
```